# Rails concern undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting an error when trying to call a concern method within a models method. I have several concerns and I've set them up in the same way. The strange thing is that one method works but the other one doesn't. Here is my code.

**param_set.rb**

```
class ParamSet < ApplicationRecord

include Searchable
include Comparable

def self.import(file, user_id, group_id = 1, project_id = nil)
    param_set_ids_map = {}
    yml = YAML.load_file(file)
    yml.each do |component, elements|
      case component
      when 'param_sets'
        elements.each do |importing_attributes|
          old_param_set_id = importing_attributes.delete('id')
          importing_attributes['user_id'] = user_id
          importing_attributes['group_id'] = group_id
          importing_attributes['project_id'] = project_id

          ParamSet.search(User.first, {search: "test"})
          ParamSet.compare(importing_attributes)

        end
      end
    end
    param_set_ids_map
  end
 end
```

**comparable.rb**

```
module Comparable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def compare(importing_attributes)
      logger.debug "Works!"
    end
  end
end
```

**searchable.rb**

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def search(current_user, params, visible: true)
      results = paged_filter(current_user, params[:scope], params[:page] || 1)
      results = results.visible if visible
      results.where!("lower(name) LIKE lower(?) OR lower(description) LIKE lower(?)", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%")
      if params[:order].blank?
        results.order!('updated_at DESC')
      else
        results.order!(params[:order])
      end
      results.reverse_order! if params[:reverse] == 'true'
      results || []
    end
  end
end
```

**The error that I get is:**

```
undefined method `compare' for #<Class:0x000056167cb01718>
```

The method `ParamSet.search(User.first, {search: "test"})` works find and doesn't give an error. The method `ParamSet.compare(importing_attributes)` however gives the error. I don't know what is going on and what the difference is between calling the two concern methods within a model method.

Can anybody explain what is going on?

Comment: try to change method name compare .

Comment: Comparable is already module of ruby. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Comparable.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
include Comparable
```

you're including the Comparable module of ruby, not your own module.  That module doesn't have a `compare` method.

Try changing your module name...

```
module Matchable
```

and the file to `matchable.rb`

and then

```
include Matchable
```

And you should be ok.